# how to return data from the query select * from table in oracle, without using cursor , with an out parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle

how to return data from the query select * from table in oracle, without using cursor , with an out parameter

Comment: Before marking negative, please give the reason or answer the query.

Comment: Did you make any attempt at solving the problem? And why must you use an out parameter?

Comment: Alas your question is rather sketchy and people are downvoting it accordingly. The question title being the same as the question body is not good. It looks like you want people to spend their time helping you but you're not investing your own time in framing a decent question. So, please edit your question to explain more about your situation. When you say *"without using cursor"* do you mean without using SYS_REFCURSOR (or similar)? If so, what datatype do you expect to use for the OUT parameter? Is this something which needs to be called from ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options.

Create and store a TYPE OBJECT EXAMPLE_REC with same structure as that of the table and compatible datatypes.

for eg: 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EXAMPLE_REC AS OBJECT (
    col1          datatype,
    col2          datatype,
    col3       datatype
);
You then don't need another local record variable.But, you need to initialize using NEW keyword as shown. You can then simply fetch the values into corresponding record elements.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example_sp(
    p_example_rec    OUT example_rec
)
    IS
BEGIN
 p_example_rec    := NEW example_rec(NULL,NULL,NULL);  --Initialization
    SELECT
       *
    INTO
        p_example_rec.col1,p_example_rec.col2,p_example_rec.col3
    FROM
        table;

END;